# Php multilingual website

Tags: php, multilingual

I am working on a website and the requirement is to make it in two languages i.e. icelandic and english.
just like facebook and other google, if a user selects a language, then the site is translated in that language.
I am not allowed to use google translator.
Any other way to do this in Php

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you building the framework from scratch or using a CMS?

Comment: i am working on custom php, from scratch

Comment: possible duplicate of [php multilingual site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1228018/php-multilingual-site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I never did it, but i did think about it :), for me i have to do something like this from scratch,

First, do not echo your String that will be displayed to your clients hardcoded, create a dictionary, this dictionary can be in any format, be it php file, xml file, json. You can also extend the functionality by adding Database in it. The main idea is to create a dictionary having all your messages that will be displayed to the user in all the languages you want to display it

consider if you do it using normal PHP FIle, use OOP built class say known as Message, then as attribute to the class add the several languages that you have to use and also some setters and getters

e.g.

```
Message
{
   english;
   french;
   .....
}
```

then in PHP, when you echo your messages, try to get the language you want to use, and then
do something like this

```
echo message.getEnglishMessage();
```

Look, I've been very generic, now decide on the type of file that you'll use and build the dictionary

Hopes it helps :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use an es.php (spanish not sure what icelandic is) and build all of the mod_rewrite off that.  You treat it exactly same as you would if it were the index.php for english.  For inputing data into the database have a column for language.  All of your queries that call data will then have the language as a condition.

Answer (score 0):

The "gettext" is the way you can go with but if you and your client are in nice understanding ask him to provide the data in language other than english as well and then in DB table there will be a column 'language' in which 'ic' or 'en' flag will be the data, and during fetching the data anywhere, according to language your sql query will contain the language as a where condition with desired flag as its value.